# inoremap ctrl h to move left in insert mode not work (it delete the left character exactly)

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

my mapping is

`.vimrc
inoremap <C-h> <left>
inoremap <c-l> <right>
inoremap <c-j> <up>
inoremap <c-k> <down>`

But, if I press `ctrl+h` in insert mode, vim will delete character on the left of cursor, which function is same as `backspace`.

Comment: Yes, traditionally the backspace key sends `Ctrl-h` so this explains it